# Is the infinitely distributed lag process strong mixing?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, mixing

Suppose the process $\{X_{t}:t\in Z\}$ is absolutely continuous distributed and strong mixing with the coefficient $\alpha(s)$ defined as
\begin{equation}
\alpha(s) \equiv \sup \{ |P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B)| : -\infty < t<\infty, A \in X^{t}_{-\infty}, B\in X^{\infty}_{t+s} \}.
\end{equation}
Here $\alpha(s) \rightarrow 0$ at a polynomial rate.

Now, consider a new process of infinitely distributed lags as $Y_{t} = \lambda(L)X_{t} \equiv X_{t} + \lambda_{1}X_{t-1} + \lambda_{2} X_{t-2} + \ldots$, where $\lambda_{k} = \rho^{k}$ with $|\rho|<1$.

My question is:  **is the process $Y_{t}$ strong mixing** (or under what conditions)? If $Y_{t}$ can be strong mixing,  what is the mixing coefficient of $Y_{t}$? The same as $\alpha(s)$？

Answer (score 1):

In general no. In the paper

[Donald W. K. Andrews. “Non-Strong Mixing Autoregressive Processes.” Journal of Applied Probability, vol. 21, no. 4, 1984, pp. 930–934. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/3213710.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3213710.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A54b76ca72e186e294014d333d36a4e47),

it is shown that even in the case where $\left(X_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z}$ is i.i.d. with a Bernoulli marginal distribution, the process $\left(Y_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z}$ is not mixing in general.

There exists conditions in the absolutely continuous case, which are contained in the paper

[Withers, C.S. Z. Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie verw Gebiete (1981) 57: 477. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01025869](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01025869.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for bringing me with the Andrews' paper. Maybe I need to refine my assumptions by specifying that the distribution of X_t is absolutely continuous.

Comment: The absolute continuity condition made my answer outdated. See edit.